# Django-CMS pages all blank after upgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.4.1

Tags: django, upgrade, django-cms

I am using Django 1.4.3 and have several sites built using Django-CMS 2.3.5.  I want to upgrade them to Django-CMS 2.4.1, so that I can then start to move to Django 1.5.

When I type `./manage runserver` from a virtualenv with Django-CMS 2.3.5, all works fine.  When I move to a virtualenv with Django-CMS 2.4.1, but otherwise the same, none of my pages can be accessed.

In the admin panel, they all have the name None.  If I edit one, the screen shows them with the correct name and all the plugins there.  If I try to save the page, the info all disappears, including the name and slug and plugins, and I get a message at the top asking me to fix the below errors (of which there are none).  I can press "publish draft", but the browser cannot find any page but `/`, and this has no plugins on it (and it still has name None in the admin panel).

If I try to add a new plugin, I get an alert saying `<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1067a9e90>`.

I am not using the `MultilingualURLMiddleware` middleware, and have `USE_I18N = False`.

I added `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` anyway (but it doesn't help if I do not).

I typed `./manage.py migrate`, `./manage cms fix-mptt` and for good measure `./manage.py cms delete_orphaned_plugins` as well.

How do I keep my pages when I migrate to the new version of Django-CMS?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are [upgrade instruction](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/develop/upgrade/2.4.html).

I think your problem is in new style CMS_LANGUAGES.

Try to set:

```
USE_I18N = True    
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    1: [
        {
            'code': 'en',
            'name': gettext('English'),
            'public': True,
            },
        ],
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['en',],
        'public': False,
        }
}
```

Also run *./manage.py cms check* to checking django CMS installation

Comment: That has fixed it! (once I have gone in and published each page again).  I thought I could shortcut the instructions by keeping USE_I18N=False, but it seems not. My site now has en/ in the URL, which it didn't before, but that's not a big problem, and I assume there's a way to get rid of that. Very much appreciated!!

Comment: try instead to set LANGUAGE_CODE to "en" instead of "en-us"

Answer (score 0):

The most crucial thing I've ever learnt in django was taking manuel backup of the `project.db` before any migration process done by `manage.py`.