# Upgrading Django to 1.5 with Django-CMS - user model issue

Tags: django, upgrade, django-cms, user-profile

I have just moved a site from Django-CMS 2.3.5 to 2.4.1 (with [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578272/django-cms-pages-all-blank-after-upgrade-from-2-3-5-to-2-4-1/) from Stackoverflow) under Django 1.4.

I am now upgrading to Django 1.5, which is only hard because I need to update the old separate user profile to a new custom user model. I followed the excellent instructions [here](http://ponytech.net/blog/2013/03/31/migrate-your-user-profile-data-django-15-custom-user-model/), and also replaced all references to `User` with `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Unfortunately Django-CMS's models apparently still refer to `User` though: when I type `manage.py runserver`, I get this error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
cms.pagemoderatorstate: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
cms.globalpagepermission: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
cms.pagepermission: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
cms.pageuser: 'user_ptr' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
cms.pageuser: 'created_by' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
cms.pageusergroup: 'created_by' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
```

How can I get Django-CMS to use the new user model?

thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen this question. I created a similar one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605453/django-1-5-extend-the-default-user-model-or-substitute-it

Comment: From https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1798 django CMS does not support AUTH_USER_MODEL at the moment. Hence what can we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others with this question, here is my summary of what I have learned from https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1798.

There are four potential options:

1. If you need your custom user model to have a name other than User, you'll need to wait.
2. You can call the custom user model User - though when I tried this, I got errors about clashes with related m2m fields. There are some further details on the above link which may help resolve this.
3. Django 1.5 still lets you use user profiles. So if you are ok with using a deprecated feature, you can still use Django-CMS 2.4 and Django 1.5 with user profiles instead of a custom user model. (I misread the Django docs here and thought user profiles were not supported in Django 1.5.)
4. You can often get away without either a user profile or a custom user model - they are best used to add data specifically for user authentication. Instead, you can use another model with a one-to-one relationship to User, and use the reverse relationship to access it.

In my case, I am going to go with #3 in the short-run and #4 in the long-run.

Comment: I didn't need to make any changes to the user profile settings to upgrade from Django 1.4 to 1.5. In fact the only change to the settings.py file I made was to add the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting. (Upgrading Django-CMS from 2.3 to 2.4 requires several more changes, but again, nothing to do with user profiles.)

Answer (score 1):

There is very simple solution. Just need to register your custom user before importing CMSPlugin. Example:

> ```
> from django.db import models
> from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models
> from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
>
> class User(AbstractUser):
>   telephone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>   email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>
> auth_models.User = User
>
> from cms.models import CMSPlugin
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I've taken a different path now, but it's great to know it's that simple.